# Don't show list during first load in sonata admin bundle in Symfony 2.1

Tags: symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I'm using `Symfony 2.1` and `Sonata Admin bundle` for admin functionality.Now I have lot of data to show in list view which I don't prefer to do by default.I want to display only filters first time and then based on filtering fields display only related data.Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your admin class you can overwrite the createQuery:

```
     /**
     * Set a standard filter for the list view
     * @param  string $context [description]
     * @return [type]          [description]
     */
    public function createQuery($context = 'list') 
    { 

            $query = $this->getModelManager()->createQuery('Company\MyBundle\Entity\Client', 'c');
                    $query->where("c.state = 'todo'");

            return $query;
    }
```

Showing nothing by default is impossible, but then again just add a query so it never returns a result? like "state = testing_my_awesome_app"